# How do I sample and conduct a random permutation test for data with unequal list lengths in R?

Tags: r, random, permutation, sampling

I have an issue where I have 2 lists of unequal lengths, and I want to conduct a random permutation test of 5000 iterations on them to find out if the difference in means for both is significant.

```
dataset1v <- c(10, 10, 5, 10, 50, 2, 5, 50, 10, 40, 50, 20, 25, 20, 10, 10, 50, 10)
dataset2v <- c(50, 10, 20, 10, 40, 10, 20, 30, 10, 10, 80, 15)
```

All the tutorials on random permutation tests out there assume equal list lengths, and so they don't apply since a warning pops up when I run it with my lists. I've tried `permutation.test.discrete` among other options, but it's always the same issue: list length is unequal. Also, I would also like to resample each data into their original list lengths (18 and 12 each). I'm a beginner at coding for R, so I have spent hours upon hours trying to figure out how to solve this issue. Would appreciate some help and pointers in the right direction! Thanks!!

Comment: Couldn't you sample with replacements 18 or 12 times respectively, from each list individually?

Comment: I made a loop for this which sort of worked in the end! I basically merged both into 1 long list and sampled each separately, then worked out the means for both and found out the mean difference, then slotted this into a pre-made empty matrix. Thanks for the suggestion!!
`a <- c()
for(i in 1:5000){
  
data <- c(10, 10, 5, 10, 50, 2, 5, 50, 10, 40, 50, 20, 25, 20, 10, 10, 50, 10, 50, 10, 20, 10, 40, 10, 20, 30, 10, 10, 80, 15)

s1 <- sample(data, size = 18, FALSE)
s2 <- sample(data, size = 12, FALSE)

M1 <- mean(s1)
M2 <- mean(s2)
MD <- (M1-M2)

a[i] <- MD}`

Comment: Well, that's not at all what I meant ;) 1. If we want to estimate the `mean` for **each** list, we shouldn't combine them but calculate the mean for each list individually. 2. Wouldn't we want to use `replace=TRUE` (otherwise we would get back the exact same sample each time)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `twot.permutation` of the `DAAG` package.

```
library("DAAG")
set.seed(42)
twot.permutation(dataset1v, dataset2v, nsim=5e3)
# [1] 0.605
```

It also includes a plotting functionality:

[image]

---

*Data*

```
dataset1v <- c(10, 10, 5, 10, 50, 2, 5, 50, 10, 40, 50, 20, 25, 20, 10, 10, 50, 10)
dataset2v <- c(50, 10, 20, 10, 40, 10, 20, 30, 10, 10, 80, 15)
```